# Integral inequality for non-negative and concave functions

Tags: inequality, probability-distributions, integral-inequality

> Is it true that the following inequality holds for any continuous, non-negative, and concave function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$?
>   $$\frac{3}{2}\,f(0)\int_0^1 xf(x)dx\leq \left(\int_0^1f(x)dx\right)^2.$$

Some thoughts. By homogeneity, we may assume that $f(0)=1$ (the case $f(0)=0$ is trivial).

Moreover, by concavity, for $x\in[0,1]$,
$$f(x)=f((1-x)\cdot 0+x\cdot 1)\geq (1-x)f(0)+xf(1)\geq 1-x$$
because $f(1)\geq 0$.

Hence the function $h(x):=f(x)-(1-x)$ is continuous, non-negative and concave on $[0,1]$ and the inequality is equivalent to
$$\frac{3}{2}\int_0^1 xh(x)dx\leq \left(\int_0^1h(x)dx\right)^2+\int_0^1h(x)dx,$$
that is
$$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{3}{2}x-1\right)h(x)dx\leq \left(\int_0^1h(x)dx\right)^2.$$
So it suffices to show 
$$\int_0^1 \left(x-\frac{2}{3}\right)h(x)dx\leq 0$$
where  $h(x)$ is a continuous, non-negative concave function on $[0,1]$ and $h(0)=0$.

Any hints or references are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I managed to conclude the proof.
We will show that
$$\int_{2/3}^1 \left(x-\frac{2}{3}\right)h(x)dx\leq 
\int_0^{2/3} \left(\frac{2}{3}-x\right)h(x)dx.$$
Since $h$ is concave and $h(0)=0$ then
$$m'x\leq h(x)\quad \mbox{for $x\in[0,2/3]$}$$
where $y=m'x$ is the secant line thru $(0,0)$ and $(2/3,h(2/3))$. Moreover
$$h(x)\leq mx+q\quad \mbox{for $x\in[0,1]$}$$
where $y=mx+q$ is the tangent line at $2/3$. Then 
$$\int_{2/3}^1 \left(x-\frac{2}{3}\right)h(x)dx\leq \int_{2/3}^1 \left(x-\frac{2}{3}\right)(mx+q)=\frac{4m}{81}+\frac{q}{18}$$
and
$$\int_0^{2/3} \left(\frac{2}{3}-x\right)h(x)dx\geq \int_0^{2/3} \left(\frac{2}{3}-x\right)(m'x)dx=\frac{4m'}{81}.$$
So it suffices to verify that
$$\frac{4m'}{81}\geq \frac{4m}{81}+\frac{q}{18}
\quad \Leftrightarrow\quad m'-m\geq \frac{9q}{8}$$
which holds because $q\geq h(0)=0$ and $m'(2/3)=m(2/3)+q$ implies $m'-m=3q/2$.